# Problem in writing to an output file using pipes

Tags: c, file, pipe, fork, ipc

I am writing a C program on working of transport layer multiplexing using OS tools. There is 3 stream of bits, in `file1`, `file2` and `file3` respectively. I read 10 bits from `file1`, `file2`, `file3` in sequence and combine them into a frame and store it in file `multiplex`.

Given, the only means of communication is pipe created by you.

Please Note: I didn't use `fwrite` function and wanted to explore more with pipes.

The corresponding code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>


int main()
{
        int fd[3][2], pid,i, ch_count=10, count, status,f;
        FILE *fp, *fp1;
        fp1=fopen("multiplex.txt", "w");
        char ch, inp[10];

        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
                pipe(fd[i]);

        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
                pid=fork();
                if(pid==0)
                {
                        printf("Inside Child process \n");
                        f=fileno(fp1);
                        close(fd[i][0]);
                        dup2(fd[i][1],f);
                        if(i==0)
                                        fp=fopen("file1.txt","r");
                        else if(i==2)
                                        fp=fopen("file2.txt","r");
                        else
                                        fp=fopen("file3.txt", "r");
                        while(1)
                        {
                                count=0;
                                while(( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF && count<=ch_count)
                                        inp[count++]=ch;
                                if(ch==EOF)
                                        exit(0);
                                printf("The string read is %s \n", inp);
                                write(fd[i][1], inp, 10);
                                sleep(3-i);
                        }
                        close(fd[i][1]);
                }
                else
                        printf("Parent process \n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The problem is:

i) I can't write anything in `multiplex` file.

ii) I read alien characters when I print the `inp` string. Moreover the strings read aren't in sequence(i.e, `file1` first, `file2` second then `file3`) . The output is:

```
The string read is s not goldAR^�q�@�      //from file 2
                                     �7�U 
The string read is l that glitR^�q�@�      //from file 2 again
                                     �7�U 
The string read is s over the R^�q�@�      //from file 1
                                     �7�U 
The string read is well that eR^�q�@�      //from file 3
                                     �7�U 
The string read is ers is not R^�q�@�      //from file 2
                                     �7�U 
The string read is oldAll thatR^�q�@�
                                     �7�U 
The string read is ds well.AllR^�q�@�
                                     �7�U 
The string read is glitters isR^�q�@�
                                     �7�U 
The string read is azy dogThe R^�q�@�
                                     �7�U 
The string read is not goldAllR^�q�@�
```

What is the problem?

Edit:
The contents of file1

```
The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_a_lazy_dog_The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_a_lazy_dog_`
```

The contents of file2

```
The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_a_lazy_dog_The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_a_lazy_dog_
```

The contents of file3

```
All's_well_that_ends_well_All's_well_that_ends_well_All's_well_that_ends_well_
```

Comment: Where is the code that writes anything in `multiplex` file?

Comment: I used `dup2` function call to represent the `write end` of pipe as `f`(file descriptor) of `multiplex` and then write to that file with `write` function

Comment: What `dup2(fd[i][1],f);` does is: close file descriptor f, then make a new file descriptor with the same number f which is a copy of file descriptor fd[i][1]. The original file descriptor f makes no difference after that, since it was closed.

Comment: That is `fd[i][1]` now contains `f`. Again the file descriptor table contains a pointer to `multiplex` corresponding to `f`. This is my understanding. This way the piece of code should have worked. Please Correct if I am wrong

Comment: No, f now contains fd[i][1]. https://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2

Comment: `dup2(f, fd[i][1])` worked. But how to obtain a sequence read from`file1` first, `file2` second, `file3` third. The sequence is sometimes 1-2-3, 2-1-3, 3-1-2 etc.

Comment: My suggestion is that you read from file1 first, file2 second, file3 third. You don't need child processes and you don't need pipes...

Comment: Please show in your question the contents of files `file1.txt` etc. and the expected output. This will allow us to test your program. The order of process execution is not fixed. If you want to enforce a certain sequence, e.g. 10 characters from file 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 etc you have to implement a synchronization mechanism. If you want to print the input of 10 characters as a string you have to make your array `inp[10]` 1 element bigger and append a `'\0'` after reading the input characters before using `printf("... %s \n", inp);` When you `exit` on `EOF` you throw away any data in `inp`.

Comment: @Bodo I have edited the question with the contents of the files. How to implement the synchronizing sequence?

Comment: @Sinister Please run your program with the files as shown in the question and copy&paste the corresponding output to the question. The output currently shown does not match the example files' contents. And show what output you want to have.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` ) Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing.

Comment: The function: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`

Comment: regarding: `sleep(3-i);`  the function: `sleep()` expects an `unsigned int`, but the variable `i` is signed.

Comment: The Parent process should be calling `wait()` or `waitpid()` for each sub process.  Otherwise the child processes might not be finished when the Parent process exits.  In the 'old' days the result would be `zombie` processes.  Now a days, that child process is attached to the `init` process

Comment: regarding: `pipe(fd[i]);`  when calling `pipe()`, (for robust code) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `pid=fork()` and following code:  The function: `fork()` has three kinds of returned values: <0 means an error occurred.  ==0 means in the child process >0 means in the parent process..  All three conditions should be checked.   Don't assume that some function worked

Comment: comparing a `char` to `EOF` can fail, depending on if (in your OS) a `char` is signed or not.

Comment: When calling C library functions, especially those that work with items not within your program, like `fopen()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `The string read is glitters isR^�q�@�
                                     �7�U 
The string read is azy dogThe R^�q�@�
                                     �7�U 
The string read is not goldAllR^�q�@�`  These strings are NOT in the posted contents of the three files

Answer (score 2):

> i) I can't write anything in multiplex file.

by

```
        fp1=fopen("multiplex.txt", "w");
        /* ... */
                        f=fileno(fp1);
                        dup2(fd[i][1],f);
```

you disassociate `fp1` from "multiplex.txt" (within the children). Using `fp1` within the children would be risky/undefined because `FILE` is usually buffered and changes in buffer position can not be shared between processes.

You will have to redesign your program (write into pipe in the children, read within the parent) to implement the wanted functionality.

> ii) I read alien characters when I print the inp string.

```
                                while(( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF && count<=ch_count)
                                        inp[count++]=ch;
                                /* ... */
                                printf("The string read is %s \n", inp);
```

does not zero-terminate it.  Either do a `inp[count] = '\0'` before the printf, or use

```
                                printf("The string read is %.*s \n", (int)count, inp);
```

Comment: To have space for adding the trailing `'\0'` the array size must be increased to `char inp[11];`